# Can someone please help me adding a simple while loop. it's better if it's releated to the script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Here's my script tried adding one kept getting an error. All help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Name:gamer
#Date Created: 12/6/2015
#last modified: 12/8/2015
#Desc/Purpose: Updating and installing apps.
DATE=$(date -d "$1" +"%m_%d_%Y");
condition=y
while [ $condition = "y" ] || [ $condition = "Y" ]
do

clear

echo -n "Do you know how to Update OS y/n:"
read answer

if [ $answer = "y" ] || [ $answer = "Y" ]; then
    echo "Good update the os then." 

elif [ $answer = "n" ]; then
    echo "would you like me to update it for you:" 
    read response
    if  [ $response = "y" ]; then
        echo "updating os!"
            sudo apt-get update os
    fi
fi
clear
echo -n "would you like to install apps:" 
read answer

if [ $answer = "y" ] || [ $answer = "Y" ]; then
        echo "A) Install Webmin"
        echo "B) Install Apache"
        echo "C) Install gnome shell"
        echo "D) get ubuntu desktop"
        echo "E) Add new user"
        echo "F) get Xubuntu Desktop"
        echo "G) Install openbox"
        echo "H) remove Libre office"
        echo "I) I don't want to install anything"
        read option
fi
        case $option in 
            A) sudo apt-get install webmin ;;
            B) sudo apt-get install apache ;;
            C) sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ;;
            D) sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ;;
            E) sudo useradd ;;
            F) sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop ;;
            G) sudo apt-get install openbox ;;
            H) sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* ;;
            I) echo "You can always do it later" ;;
            *) echo "Please select one of the options" ;;
        esac


done
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting, but **please** help to improve your question: at least tell us **what** error you kept getting. What do you want the loop to do?

Comment: What do you exactly want @Gamer? And what error do you encounter?

Comment: I can see your `while do` loop has no `condition` change in it so it will constantly loop and ask the same questions over and over no matter what you type in.

Comment: You probably want to include a 'quit' option.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you didn't explain what is the specific error you want to fix,
but in any case, this command:

```
sudo apt-get update os
```

Will give an error:

> ```
> E: The update command takes no arguments
> ```

The fix is trivial, sort of:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

"sort of", because it doesn't do what the `echo` statement says:

```
echo "updating os!"
sudo apt-get update
```

This just updates the package index, doesn't update anything in the operating system. Perhaps you're looking for:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Not sure if it's a problem, but your `while` loop never exits,
because the `condition` variable is set to `y` in the beginning and it never changes later.
Perhaps you want to set it to `n` at some point,
or add a `break` statement.
It would be also good to rename "condition" to something that actually means something.
Or to make this explicitly an infinite loop, change it to `while true`.